# SetForegroundWindow fails on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

**The Scenario**
I have my main application which was originally written in Borland C++ that is being started by a C# .Net application.  This main application occasionally opens a modal dialog from a process called BRWSEXE.  After a modal dialog window pops up, you could accidentally click somewhere in the main application (not on the dialog) causing the focus to briefly change to the main application sending the modal dialog behind it in the Z order.  But you can't actually do anything on the main application, it is locked up by that modal dialog window that must close first before you can continue.

**The Problem**
Using the .net application that launches everything, I can seek out instances of BRWSEXE that are related to the main application and force them into the foreground.  This tactic works flawlessly everywhere I've tested it so far (Windows xp, Windows 7, Windows Server 2003 R2) but it doesn't work on Windows Server 2008.  So as far as I can tell, my code works fine...but something in that environment is throwing it off.

**My Code**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr AttachThreadInput(IntPtr idAttach, IntPtr idAttachTo, bool fAttach);


private void PushBRWSEXEToFront()
{
    //Make sure MyApplication is running
    if (Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApplicationName").Length == 1)
    {
        Process[] brwsProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("BRWSEXE"); //Locate any processes for the browse dialog windows
        for (int x = brwsProc.Length - 1; x > -1; x--)
        {
            //Make sure the browse window we are looking at is associated with the active program we are looking at
            if (brwsProc[x].SessionId == Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId
                || brwsProc[x].SessionId == Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApplicationName")[0].SessionId)
            {
                //attach to the main applications thread
                AttachThreadInput(brwsProc[x].MainWindowHandle, Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApplicationName")[0].MainWindowHandle, true);

                //Call Set foreground window to push the browse window in front of the rest of the program.
                SetForegroundWindow(brwsProc[x].MainWindowHandle);

                //Detach from the main thread
                AttachThreadInput(brwsProc[x].MainWindowHandle, Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApplicationName")[0].MainWindowHandle, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AttachThreadInput` declaration is completely wrong. It returns `bool`, arguments are `uint`. And you are using it wrong, you are supposed to pass the thread ID, not a window handle. You'll need `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`.

And you are not checking for errors at all so you obviously can't diagnose failure.  `SetLastError` property required, retrieve the error with `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`. Use pinvoke.net for better pinvoke declarations.

Comment: Forgive me I am a novice and I must have had a bad source of initial information. With what you've said that means that only my SetForegroundWindow calls were working since it does successfully bring the window to the foreground. But none of this helps me figure out why it works anywhere but on Windows Server 2008.  

Thanks for the information on getting errors from these calls. I will be sure to use it while I continue to try to get this working.

Comment: The AttachThreadInput() calls are there for a reason.  Without them, SetForegroundWindow() has a very high possibility of not actually bringing the window into the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [`SwitchToThisWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and although MSDN says that it could be removed in future versions of Windows, it is still working for me.

Comment: @MichałMokrzycki Yes, it should show and bring the window into the foreground.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I changed my code to use that function instead but I'm getting the same results. It works using the other operating systems but it fails using Windows Server 2008.